# How to check session in Node.js Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I try to check if session in Express 4 is exist:

```
if(req.session.user == undefined) {}
```

It gives me error:

```
 Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

How I can check if exist value in session?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [source](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/):

> **How to use Express Session ?**
>
> Before heading to actual code, i want to put few words about
>   express-session module. to use this module, you must have to include
>   express in your project. Like for all packages, we have to first
>   include it.
>
> ```
> server.js
> var express = require('express');
> var session = require('express-session');
> var app = express();
> ```
>
> After this, we have to initialize the session and we can do this by
>   using following.
>
> ```
> app.use(session({secret: 'ssshhhhh'}));
> ```
>
> Here ‘secret‘ is used for cookie handling etc but we have to put some
>   secret for managing Session in Express.
>
> Now using ‘request‘ variable you can assign session to any variable.
>   Just like we do in PHP using $_SESSION variable. for e.g
>
> ```
> var sess;
> app.get('/',function(req,res){
>     sess=req.session;
>     /*
>     * Here we have assign the 'session' to 'sess'.
>     * Now we can create any number of session variable we want.
>     * in PHP we do as $_SESSION['var name'].
>     * Here we do like this.
>     */
>     sess.email; // equivalent to $_SESSION['email'] in PHP.
>     sess.username; // equivalent to $_SESSION['username'] in PHP.
> });
> ```
>
> After creating Session variables like sess.email , we can check
>   whether this variable is set or not in other routers and can track the
>   Session easily.

Comment: I ask how to check if exists session, not how to use

Comment: I dont need to create session and after check it

Answer (score 13):

Firstly it depends on the library you are using, maybe some libraries have utilities for that, I assume you're using `express-session`.

> This is just Okay:

```
if(req.session.user){}
```

> They are useless:

```
if(typeof req.session.user !== "undefined"){}

if(typeof req.session.user !== "undefined" || req.session.user === true){}
```

**The reason**: `req.session` is an object, just like normal objects:

```
var obj = { name : "adam" }
```

If you try to get **obj.age** which it doesn't exist and defined,
the **getter function** of the object, firstly check if it exists or not, if it's not, it wouldn't produce a **fatal error** and instead it assigns that property to **undefined** value.

That's cool, so `obj.age` get's **undefined** ( JS has `undefined` as a value type), moreover `undefined` is a falsy value (when you coerce it to boolean it becomes false, so it's falsy), which means you can simply check it in conditional statements like this: `if(obj.age){}`

Answer (score 5):

You can't just create a session without any middleware (Im assuming this is what you've tried).

Read up on the express-session middleware docs, found  here:

https://github.com/expressjs/session

Basic implementation example:

Create a session:

```
app.use(session({
  genid: function(req) {
    return genuuid() // use UUIDs for session IDs
  },
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}))
```

To read a session:

```
// Use the session middleware
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

// Access the session as req.session

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var sess = req.session
  if (sess.views) {
    sess.views++
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<p>views: ' + sess.views + '</p>')
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (sess.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
    res.end()
  } else {
    sess.views = 1
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
  }
})
```

There are a number of tutorials you can find online, e.g:

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/session-management-expressjs-web-application/

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are facing is maybe you are not using the session middleware in ALL of your requests. 
You can check it the **following** way :

1. Add this to all of your routes :

```js
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat',resave:false,saveUninitialized:false, cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
```

2. Authentication Route :

```js
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //login logic here

  //if login successfull
  req.session.user = username //your unique identifier
  req.send("Hurray! logged in");

  //else
  req.send("Credentials error");

});
```

3. Check in any route:

```js
router.get('/dashboard', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user)
    //do stuff here
  else
  //redirect to login page

})
```

This works :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else finds this in 2023, make sure you are setting up sessions BEFORE bodyparser, otherwise it won't work.