# Cannot set property "name" of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, express-session

So I'm new to `express`(and backend as whole) and to be fair I don't know exactly how to use `sessions`(I started by using cookies first but then I heared that `sessions` are better to maintain user's state) so I installed `express-session` and did like this post did:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37608202/5737650

Where I saved the session in a variable(`sess`) and then I used to get the informations out but the problem is that it seems like sess is only the `cookie` object and not the other informations I need to save user's inputs in which gave me this error:

```
Cannot set property "name" of undefined
```

This is my code which is its job is to register the user, save the data to database then when it goes to login page, it checks if his inputs exist in database or not, if not then it will give me a `console.log`, if exist then it will save the data to the session so that I can maintain its state later but it gives me the above error when I enter the correct inputs:

```
// Importing modules/packages
let connection = require("./Connection.js");
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
var session = require("express-session");
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "1E3ESS3DSS4DS4",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      path: "/",
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60,
      httpOnly: true
    },
    user: {
      name: "",
      password: "",
      status: ""
    }
  })
);
let urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

// Server and routing
app.listen(3000, function() {});
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.get("/Signup", (req, res) => {
  res.render("Register");
});
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.redirect("Login");
});
app.get("/Login", function(req, res) {
  res.render("Login");
});

// Database's Connection
connection.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    throw "ERROR! " + err;
  }
});

// Requesting and Receiving Data from body parser
app.post("/Signup", urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  res.render("Register");
  connection.query(
    `insert into users (Username, User_Password, Email_Address) values ("${
      req.body.Username
    }", ${req.body.Password}, "${req.body.Email}")`,
    function(err) {
      if (err) throw "An error has happened while excuting the query " + err;
      console.log("Query got excuted successfully!");
    }
  );
});

app.post("/Login", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  let sess = req.session;
  console.log(sess);
  connection.query(
    `SELECT Username FROM users WHERE User_Password = ? AND Username = ?`,
    [req.body.Password, req.body.Username],
    function(err, results) {
      if (results.length === 0) {
        console.log(
          "Sorry, this username/password doesn't exist in our database."
        );
      } else {
        console.log("Logined successfully!");
        sess.user.name = req.body.Username;
        sess.user.password = req.body.Password;
        sess.user.status = "online";
      }
      res.render("Login");
    }
  );
});
```

How I fix this and get the result I want(maintain its state as logged all throught the website)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in the code.

1. Initially, the session object would not have `user` object. Thus `sess.user` would be `undefined`. So the first error `Cannot set property "name" of undefined` makes sense. You might want to initialize `sess.user` to empty object first.
2. With the `POST` the request, you need to call the `.save()` on the `req.session` to save it. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531143/sessions-wont-save-in-node-js-without-req-session-save)

Here is the code I tried on my machine:

```
app.post("/Login", (req, res) => {
    let sess = req.session;
    res.send(sess);
    sess.user = {};
    sess.user.name = req.body.Username;
    sess.user.password = req.body.Password;
    sess.user.status = "online";
    req.session.save();
});
```

You could do something like this:

```
app.post("/Login", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    let sess = req.session;
    console.log(sess);
    connection.query(
        `SELECT Username FROM users WHERE User_Password = ? AND Username = ?`,
        [req.body.Password, req.body.Username],
        function(err, results) {
            if (results.length === 0) {
                console.log(
                    "Sorry, this username/password doesn't exist in our database."
                );
            } else {
                console.log("Logined successfully!");
                sess.user = {
                    name: req.body.Username,
                    password: req.body.Password,
                    status: "online"
                };
            }
            req.session.save();
            res.render("Login");
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why I should put res.send(sess), why sess.user = {} why not just making it directly {} why req.session.save()? Can you explain these please more? I'm new to express and session thing.

Comment: Umm No. You do not need `res.send(sess)`. I did that so that I can easily see the session variables in the response. About `req.session.save()`, I recommend going through the link I posted and then ask exactly which point you do not understand

Comment: I am not clear what are you asking by your this line =>  why sess.user = {} why not just making it directly {}

Comment: @Anad Undavia I mean what's the difference between session {user: //code} and sess.something = {//code}}? Isn't sess is the whole session object or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Yes, `sess` is the whole session object. And it is completely up to you to either user `sess.user.name = 'xxx'` or `sess.name = 'xxx'` ( you, however, can not do `sess = 'xxx'` )

Comment: You didn't get what I was trying to say but fine, thank you a lot for the explaining! it was really useful! @Anand Undavia

Comment: Thanks :) If you want more help, let's chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Comment: There is a problem, your way works perfectly but when I want to check if username/password exists in req.session in other routes, it shows me an error that req.session.user.name doesn't exist. What I do?

Comment: First, check if the `req.session.user` exists or not, if it does, check if `req.session.user.name` exists\ or not.